# Displaying progress bar before opening Acitivity in Android?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-listview, android-fragments

I have two Activity A & B . On click of button of Activity A , i am opening activity B . On create method of Activity B , it is take more time to open activity due to method execution . I want to display progress bar while Activity B will opening , after opening progress bar need to close .

Activity B :-

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       BindStaticValues();
GetCalculationOptions(); //calculation from web server 
 }
  public void BindStaticValues()
 {

//standard 
BindStandard(); //static spinner (not db)           

//Spinner 1
array1 = new ArrayList<ObjectMaterial>();
Adapter1 = new DescriptionAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        array1 );
Adapter1 
.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
sp1.setAdapter(Adapter1 );

//Spinner 2
array2 = new ArrayList<ObjectMaterial>();
Adapter2 = new DescriptionAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        array2 );
Adapter2 
.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
sp2.setAdapter(Adapter2 );

 }
```

Please suggest me any usable link or sample code.

Comment: show code of activity B

Comment: As it is taking a more time in method execution in B activity. Try to run the method in Async task.

Comment: check now again question for info

Comment: You should use AsyncTask for you purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take this example: http://android.okhelp.cz/asynctask-example-android-with-progressbar/

U can call you're method in the doBackground Job and after this u hide u'r progressbar and start u're activity. I think thats all

Comment: I have call my function in doinbackgound functions for asyn but the problem is that we need to call this function in h.post because from function i am felling spinner values . But still now , my activity is opening slow , not displaying progress bar for asyc .

Answer (score 3):

For that purpose, You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

You can use 2 methods inside AsyncTask:

1. `onPreExecute()` - To display progress bar
2. `doInBackground()` - To perform long running task (in your case, execute method)
3. `onPostExecute()` - To perform UI update task or start new activity.